# Can I import data from SQL Server into SPSS?

Tags: c#, sql-server, spss

I am writing a C# form based application that stores its data in SQL Server 2005.

My client wants to use this data in SPSS.

My original plan had been to create a database view which matches the SPSS structure.  This could then be exported as a CSV file and copied into SPSS.

However, I just heard there may be a way to import data from a relational database directly within SPSS?  I haven't been able to work out how to do this (I can see an export to db option, but not an import)

Does anybody know if data import from SQL Server is possible in SPSS?  Or if there is an easier way to achieve this than by using the approach I outlined above?

Many thanks!

--- L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add to this, you can import from a number of ODBC-compliant data sources.  IMO, SPSS does this much easier than SAS, if you were comparing those two tools only.  It is true that you have to save an ODBC connection up front, but after that it is a breeze!

In addition, with newer versions of SPSS (I know it was in Versions 18+), you can **WRITE** data back to a database. This is an unbelievebe feature and they make it very easy to do.  We recently started leveraging this feature at work and it gets around needing to store multiple versions of the save SPSS file on a shared network drive, helps with reporting (can feed predictions) to a data warehouse that helps with reporting (i.e. Cognos), etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

For any future searchers... I solved this by using the "Open Database" option under File menu, then selecting "New Query..."

I had to add appropriate ODBC drivers, then was able to create new joins between tables, and rename variables as required.

Easy once I stopped looking for something called 'import'! DOH!